# Vertical align flexslider content with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've built [this](http://www.atomized.tv/new/) responsive site that is running [Woo Themes Flexslider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/).

I'd like to vertically align the video and copy to the middle of the page. I've tried using flexbox on `<div class="center"></div>`, but the position of the content is being pushed to the top.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it because the `<div>` doesn't have a set width and height?

Comment: Please post the relevant code, or a simulation. Eventually, if the link to your site changes or dies, then this question would lose value. Make the question complete. That said, here's some guidance for centering with flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll get a simulation running on here tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the flexbox way doesn't work but you can do it with this code:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```